# Flutter A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run: error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, android-sdk-manager

I install flutter but give some error.  I know a lot of solution for this error but them are not fix for me. How can ı solve this problem ?

My JAVA_HOME at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2

1. command

```
C:\Users\Flamador>flutter doctor --android-licenses

A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\Users\Flamador\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

2. command

```
C:\Users\Flamador>C:\Users\Flamador\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager
--update 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

ı try this command but ...

3. command

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee
```

Again

4. command

```
C:\Users\Flamador>C:\Users\Flamador\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all modules are available by default in JDK 13. To solve your problem, its a lot easier if you set your `JAVA_HOME` to JDK 1.8 and run the update command.