# fixed Android License Status Unknown.flutter instalation

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk

help me fix an error that occurred during flutter installation

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263234/cannot-run-flutter-doctor-android-licenses
See if this helps

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your commands and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error log, I guess it's self-explanatory that you need to try running:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

which should prompt you to accept licenses, just type `y` and press enter.

**Update:**
Well, I actually didn't notice that you already try running this command, but then it seems you need to set up or install/update the Android sdk with the required configurations.

**Update #2:**

1. Scroll down and Download Command line tools only from this link [https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads]
2. Put your Downloaded file (tools) in this location C:\Users\ABC\AppData\ABC\Android\Sdk
3. close your android studio, and again open android studio. And check update.
4. Open the command line and past (flutter doctor --android-licenses) ,don’t use parenthesis.
5. And press ‘y’ for accept
6. Run flutter doctor you should be good.